# How to create a formatted String out of a literal in Rust?

Tags: string, formatting, rust, string-literals

I'm about to return a string depending the given argument.

```
fn hello_world(name:Option<String>) -> String {
    if Some(name) {
        return String::formatted("Hello, World {}", name);
    }
}
```

**This is a not available associated function!** - I wanted to make clear what I want to do. I browsed the doc already but couldn't find any string builder functions or something like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since [Rust 1.58](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356898/is-there-a-way-to-pass-named-arguments-to-format-macros-without-repeating-the-va) it's possible to use [named parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#named-parameters), too.

```rust
fn hello_world(name: Option<&str>) -> String {
    match name {
        Some(n) => format!("Hello, World {n}"),
        None => format!("Who are you?"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41):

Use the [`format!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html):

```rust
fn hello_world(name: Option<&str>) -> String {
    match name {
        Some(n) => format!("Hello, World {n}"),
        None => format!("Who are you?"),
    }
}
```

In Rust, formatting strings uses the macro system because the format arguments are typechecked at compile time, which is implemented through a *procedural macro*.

There are other issues with your code:

1. You don't specify what to do for a `None` - you can't just "fail" to return a value.
2. The syntax for `if` is incorrect, you want `if let` to pattern match.
3. Stylistically, you want to use implicit returns when it's at the end of the block.
4. In *many* (but not all) cases, you want to accept a `&str` instead of a `String`.

See also:

- [Is there a way to pass named arguments to format macros without repeating the variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45356898/155423)