# Is there a way to pass named arguments to format macros without repeating the variable names?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

With new versions of Rust, you can simplify structure initialization like this:

```
Foo {
    a: a,
    b: b,
}
```

to this

```
Foo { a, b }
```

Is it possible to do something similar for `format!`/`println!`-like macros?

For now I need to write it like this:

```
let a = "a";
let b = "b";
write!(file, "{a} is {b}", a = a, b = b).unwrap();
```

Is it possible to write my own macros with an API like this:

```
let a = "a";
let b = "b";
my_write!(file, "{a} is {b}", a, b).unwrap();
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are asking, but you don't need named formatting arguments, you can stick to positional arguments: `write!(file, "{} is {}", a, b)`, or `write!(file, "{0} is {1}", a, b)`.

Comment: @E_net4 No, I not need numbers, I want names, in have ~ 5 arguments so I need name for them, like `{long_word}`,  `{another_long_word}`

Comment: You may wish to read the documentation on [std::fmt](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html). The code that you wrote does not seem to do what you want. Can you create a [MCVE] that shows how you are currently formatting the struct?

Comment: I think that using the *variable* `a` with the *string value* `"a"` is likely confusing your example, especially with the text `"{a} is {b}"`. Try using something concrete like `name` and `age` instead.

Comment: @E_net4 The question is, does the formatter allow `a` to be intepreted as `a = a` in formatters, like it allows `a` to be short for `a: a` in struct initializers. The answer is No AFAIK?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Indeed, it took me a while to understand the question. Thanks. As for its feasibility, I haven't managed to wrap my head around it yet. :)

Comment: @loganfsmyth I know that it impossible, the question is it possible to create wrapper for std format macroses that do what I want.

Comment: if you're lazy you can just stuff them into a tuple and `{:?}` it since tuples implement Debug

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[RFC 2795](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2795-format-args-implicit-identifiers.html) has been accepted and [implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67984). Starting in Rust 1.58, you will be able to go beyond your desired syntax:

```rust
write!(file, "{a} is {b}").unwrap();
```

Before then, you can write your own wrapper around `println!` and friends:

```rust
macro_rules! myprintln {
    ($fmt:expr, $($name:ident),*) => { println!($fmt, $($name = $name),*) }
}

fn main() {
    let a = "alpha";
    let b = "beta";
    myprintln!("{a} is {b}", a, b);
}
```

This will likely always be limited compared to the full formatter macro, but it may be sufficient for your case.

Answer (score -1):

As of [1.5](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.5.0/std/macro.format!.html) this is the closest you can get natively.

```
my_write!(file, "{} is {}", a, b).unwrap();
```

Additionally as Shepmaster pointed out my answer will eventually become obsolete (I'll try to remember to remove it when that happens).  If you want to keep an eye on the (to be implemented) syntax they propose you can check [this github ticket](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67984) they linked

Comment: OP asked this question on 2017-07-27; [Rust 1.18 was the stable release at the time](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1180-2017-06-08). In the question, they are already using the syntax you propose (`write!(file, "{a} is {b}", a = a, b = b).unwrap();`). The specific question is about removing the duplication of `a = a`.

Comment: I gave my upvote because I just wanted to know this answer and google found it :)

Comment: @Shepmaster that is not the syntax I demonstrated, though I'm open to making adjustments since it seems you may have misunderstood (I feel clarity is important).  If you look the X does not use the = allowing for a more concise declaration.  Granted it is without the explicit naming (which prevents repetition and out of order assigning) but the op didn't request that.  Additionally I explicitly mentioned this is for 1.5 (not the 1.18 the OP was using).  I added my answer because this still shows up in searches on google.

Comment: *but the op didn't request that* — sure they did: "Is there a way to **pass named arguments** to format macros". The syntax `{}` isn't a named argument, it's a *positional* argument. They even show what example they'd like: `my_write!(file, "{a} is {b}", a, b)`.

Comment: *I explicitly mentioned this is for 1.5 (not the 1.18 the OP was using)* — sure, but why? The syntax you show has existed since 1.0. Why the arbitrary choice of 1.5?

Comment: Because that's the version I tested it on, and for which I had documentation.  If you provide me a link to the original update and documentation I'd be happy to update the reference

Comment: I see, so what you're saying is the answer I proposed was already mentioned in comments and rejected by the OP?